# yui3 grids not working on Firefox

Tags: css, yui3

I am trying to make a 3 column YUI3 grids with

1/2 | 3/8 | 1/8

This works fine on Chrome and Safari, but on Firefox the 1/8th column wraps under the 1/2 column.

What am i missing?

[Here is the site](http://zmgc.net/)

Answer (score 0):

i had the wrong yui3-g setup, http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssgrids/